# word for when you realize you've said something stupid

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

Say you're trying to lie to someone about why you weren't in class or whatever. You blurt out the first excuse that comes to mind (maybe like "I caught typhoid fever", or something similarly hard to believe) but once you've said it, you immediately realize how terrible of a lie that was. So the (negative) emotion you'd get in that moment would be...?

The closest *phrase* I can find is "instant regret" but I swear to God there's an actual word for this feeling. **It's not** *flustered*, *embarrassed*, *ashamed*, *humiliated*, or any of the other synonyms for 'embarrassed' I can find.

An example that encapsulates that moment is the famous, [*We're all fine here*](https://ytcropper.com/cropped/3b5be510c387448) scene from Star Wars

Also just realized it's probably an adjective I'm looking for and not a noun. *D'oh*!

Comment: Failure to put brain in gear before putting mouth into motion.

Comment: Homer Simpson would say, "Doh!" But, really, this question is too broad as it currently stands. Also, your addition of *ignosecond* isn't a feeling . . .

Comment: true, I'll try to be more specific

Comment: There's no need to write what you have changed or modified in your post. Anyone can see its history by clicking on the [timestamp](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/472164/revisions). The video clip BTW is perfect, love it!

Comment: thanks! probably should've guessed the edit history is visible, :p

Comment: Not a word, but a phrase that springs to mind is "could have kicked myself!" - see c2. here: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/kicked

Comment: also.. "d'oh!" - https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/d'oh ; which to Homer Simpson's shame, was in use as early as 1945 according to that dictionary reference.

Answer (score 2):

Chagrined, I believe, is what you're after. A hit of embarrasment, a bit of shame, and oh, that regret.

> **chagrin** *verb* (be chagrined)
>   Feel distressed or humiliated.
>   ‘But he went on nationwide television and said that, and that he was chagrined by it and embarrassed by it.’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chagrin)

Answer (score 0):

Mortification, or feeling mortified, although that's a very strong version. More moderate would be chagrin, as the previous responder wrote.